# How to access outlets of a custom view from another controller that embedded it?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a custom view (CustomView1) class. It has some outlets.
I have another viewController which has uses this view in its xib file:
I added an empty view and set its class to "CustomView1"

```
@interface CustomView : UIView 
{
    IBOutlet ExtendedTextField *t1;
    IBOutlet ExtendedTextField *t2;
    IBOutlet ExtendedTextField *t3;
}
```

---

In viewController xib file I added that empty view with the class of CustomView

---

```
@interface ViewController1 : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet CardNumberViewController *customView;
}
```

---

```
@implementation ViewController1

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   // Here I can access customView. Is it possible to access t1, t2 and t3?
}
```

**Is it possible to access t1, t2 and t3 in ViewController1?**

Comment: No. If you want to use one class properties in another class, you need take them as @property(Strong, Nonatomic) IBOutlet ExtendedTextField *t1. Like this.

Comment: get a reference to the custom view in the controller and you can access its iboutlets through this reference and can assign it to any variable of the same type declared in the controller

Comment: I think you need to clean up your code and comments a little. It is not clear how classes and objects relate. For example, `CardNumberViewController` is a view controller but its object name implies it's a view. You write about `CustomView1` but there is no such view. You do not show where `CustomView` class is used. etc.